# NotePad ++ Extract words inside []

Tags: notepad++

For my current task, I have JSON data like below in my NotePad++ file,

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 85,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "mycluster",
            "_type": "subjectData",
            "_id": "24",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "CaseA": [
                  "Personal and Culinary Services"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "mycluster",
            "_type": "subjectData",
            "_id": "30",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "CaseA": [
                  "na"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "mycluster",
            "_type": "subjectData",
            "_id": "31",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "CaseA": [
                  "Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, and Related Sciences"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]    
}
```

I need to extract CaseA value alone from the entire file,

```
"CaseA": [
            "Personal and Culinary Services"
         ]
```

Like, "Personal and Culinary Services".

Is there any way to do like this, "CaseA":[$1] ??

Any help/suggestion/idea would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is a particularly bad tool for parsing JSON.  A JSON parser would be much better, but we can try to write a regex for this:

**Find:**

```
(?:(?!"CaseA":).)*("CaseA":\s+\[[^\]]*\])
```

**Replace:**

```
$1\n
```

The basic idea in the pattern above is to consume everything until we hit the start of the text `"CaseA":`.  At that point, we consume *and* capture the CaseA text.  In the replacement, we only use the text you want to retain.

I have not tested this in Notepad++ but the matching certainly works in the demo below.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

A two step solution:

First step:

- Search menu > Mark...
- Find: `^\h*"CaseA": \[\R\K[^\]\n\r]+`
- Check `Mark lines`
- <kbd>Find all</kbd>

[image]

Second step:

- Search menu > Bookmark
- Remove unmarked lines

**Result for given example:**

```
              "Personal and Culinary Services"
              "na"
              "Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, and Related Sciences"
```